# cycle detected error in internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i am getting error cycle detected error in internet explorer 11 (win7), however my app is working fine on other browser's e.g.: chrome,Firefox

i am using ui-router and if user is not authenticated then I am re-routing to another route

```
 this.$state.go('auth',{returnUrl:location.hash});
```

with a return URL, in this process I am getting the error, I am using nodejs server, angular 1.3.8 and ui-router -0.2.13

please suggest me what are reason's when this error occurs and what can be the possible fix

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding your local host url and the other URL you are trying to re-route into your browser proxy exception and hit the application again in new browser.